# Where to find the default `display` style attribute for a HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, I was not sure what the default `display` style attribute of `<img>` tag is (`inline` or `block` or `inline-block`). Therefore, I tried to find this information in the [img term of MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img). But I didn't find whether it is `inline` or `block` in the MDN document.

Does anyone have ideas about where can I find this information?

Is there any official/canonical documentation to describe this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `display` style attribute of `<img>` tag is `inline` and its mentioned in this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) for inline elements.

> The following elements are "inline":
>
> - b, big, i, small, tt
> - abbr, acronym, cite, code, dfn, em, kbd, strong, samp, var
> - a, bdo, br, img, map, object, q, script, span, sub, sup
> - button, input, label, select, textarea

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

by default img tag is inline.

You can check the following [link](http://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/) for reference.

These are the exemplary default style sheets proposed by the W3C in the specifications of [CSS 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#appendix-a), [CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html), and [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)

Comment: Thanks! but is there any official/canonical documentation to describe this...

Comment: @hanfeisun, i got some w3c official links which i have updated in my answer. It has the different display properties listed per tag. Hope it helps.